# Calculating probability of winning Power Ball

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Today I tried to calculate the probability of winning a jackpot in Power Ball California Lottery. There are 1-59 numbers from which you have to guess 5 out of 5 and 1-35 numbers from which you have to guess 1 (mega). As you all know you win when you get 5 out of 5 and 1 mega number. So I tried to calculate it the following way:
$$
\frac{
\left( \begin{array}{c}
5 \\
5 \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{c}
54 \\
0 \end{array} \right)
}
{
\left( \begin{array}{c}
59 \\
5 \end{array} \right)
}
*
\frac{
\left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{c}
34 \\
0 \end{array} \right)
}
{
\left( \begin{array}{c}
34 \\
1 \end{array} \right)
}
$$
but I am getting 1 in about 37 million when on the back of the ticket is states that the probability is 1 in 175 million.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the order of the 5 numbers matter?

Comment: you have to choose 5 out 54 and get all 5 right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numerators don't make much sense. You have to select $5$ numbers out of $59$: you can do this in $59 \choose 5$ ways. You also have to select $1$ number out of $35$: you can do this in $35$ ways. Those choices are independent from each other, so we multiply them and find: ${59 \choose 5} \cdot 35 = 175223510$.

Comment: Great, that makes sense, thank you.